# Issues after installing a C# app on a Windows Machine (never happened before in others)

Tags: c#, winforms

thanks for reading my post, i just installed an app in a windows pc, firs time is showing me this message, and a i do not know what can be happening, Any help would be appreciated

First time after a lot of other installs

```
Consulte el final de este mensaje para obtener más detalles sobre cómo invocar a la depuración 
Just-In-Time (JIT) en lugar de a este cuadro de diálogo.

************** Texto de la excepción **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Clase no registrada (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
   en System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
   en System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
   en System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
   en System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
   en System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
   en System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
   en System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   en System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()
   en WindowsFormsApplication2.FormAuth.InitializeComponent()
   en WindowsFormsApplication2.FormAuth..ctor(Int32 nivel_usuario2, Int32 id_usuarioY)
   en WindowsFormsApplication2.Login.Mostrar_Sistema(Int32 nivel_usuario, Int32 id_usuarioZ)
   en WindowsFormsApplication2.Login.Accion_Click1()
   en WindowsFormsApplication2.Login.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Ensamblados cargados **************
mscorlib
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.0.30319.296 (RTMGDR.030319-2900)
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
WindowsFormsApplication2
    Versión del ensamblado: 1.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 1.0.0.0
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/BIO-H/WindowsFormsApplication2.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.0.30319.1002 built by: RTMGDR
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.0.30319.1001 built by: RTMGDR
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.0.30319.1001 built by: RTMGDR
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.0.30319.237 (RTMGDR.030319-2300)
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.0.30319.233 built by: RTMGDR
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.0.30319.233 built by: RTMGDR
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Management
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Management.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.DataSetExtensions
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
----------------------------------------
AxInterop.GrFingerXLib
    Versión del ensamblado: 1.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 1.0.0.0
    Código base: file:///C:/Program%20Files/BIO-H/AxInterop.GrFingerXLib.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------
mscorlib.resources
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.0.30319.235 (RTMGDR.030319-2300)
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/mscorlib.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms.resources
    Versión del ensamblado: 4.0.0.0
    Versión Win32: 4.0.30319.235 built by: RTMGDR
    Código base: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll
----------------------------------------

************** Depuración JIT **************
Para habilitar la depuración Just In Time (JIT), el archivo de configuración de esta
aplicación o equipo (machine.config) debe tener el
valor jitDebugging establecido en la sección system.windows.forms.
La aplicación también se debe compilar con la depuración
habilitada

Por ejemplo:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

Cuando esté habilitada la depuración JIT, cualquier excepción no controlada
se enviará al depurador JIT registrado en el equipo
en lugar de controlarlo mediante el cuadro de diálogo.
```

Comment: This is not a programming question.  Because the message is not in English its difficult to tell what you are asking.

Comment: That app is trying to access a class and the class isn't there. If you're not the one who coded it, take it to the app's author.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909026/interface-not-registered-error-when-visual-studio-2010-program-runs-on-win-7-32b?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Your framework is off. It looks like your application is in 4.0 and the machine you are installing it on is in something else.

If the machine can handle it try installing the .net 4.0 framework.

[This location mentions(As well as english version of the error)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f9ab6d1c-6d4e-4453-814f-96a92a081f22/systemconfigurationconfigurationerrorsexception-an-error-occurred-creating-the-configuration) that you need a minimum of v3.5 when on Vista or later.

Comment: Downloading and installing, i will let you know the results

Comment: I'd vote for this one too.

Comment: Well i did it, after all efforts, and downloading all the updates i could install, i think it must be a framework issue, anybody please could remove me the questions ban?